# TextView strips off trailing dot

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` whose text is set dynamically:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24dp" />
```

And here is the code that sets the text:

```
input.setText("12345"); // shows 12345
input.setText("123456"); // shows 123456
```

But whenever I pass a string that ends with a dot, the dot gets removed:

```
input.setText("12345."); // shows 12345
input.setText("123456."); // shows 123456
```

The `TextView` is wide enough to display the whole text.

How can I make it display the full text, without discarding the trailing dot?

Comment: Can you show us the parent element, too? I highly doubt that the dot is cut away for real. Did you check your screen with the Android Studio Layout Inspector (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)? Did you set a breakpoint to double check that the correct text is set to the TextView? Can you show us the logic when setting the text "dynamically"?

Comment: Thank you, by setting breakpoints I could identify the error.

Comment: good for you, glad I could be your rubber duck ;)

Comment: Might now think of making use of the bounty for another topic :)

Comment: dont worry about the bounty. Give it to Shubham, he will probably be happier about it than me :)

Comment: Ok he gets it :)

Answer (score 0):

The dots won't get removed with these steps.
Need to debug for that TextView.
Make sure you must initialise input from that layout inflator(view).

```
input = view.findViewById(R.id.input);
input.setText("12345.") // It will show "12345."
```